# QT Linguist ts file names in pro file

Tags: qt, qt-linguist

How does QT Linguist know the ts file defined in the project file is for a specific language?  (Is the "_ja" characters in the name how it determines the language? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.)

I have a ts file defined as "testdata_ja.ts" in the project file.  Running lupdate, the file is generated.  In the ts file there is a line:

```
<TS version="2.1" language="ja_JP">
```

lupdate seemed to figure it out, but nothing was translated, all entries are "unfinished".  I put an entry in the code that was in the Japanese phrase book.

Comment: What do you mean by that ? The project does not know which file if for which language, you have to map the files to specific languages yourself in your application.

Comment: Yea, what do you mean? You realize you actually have to translate the file and mark the translations as "finished" right?  The phrasebook is just a hint/help for the human translator, `lupdate` will never automatically translate anything for you (thankfully!).

Comment: Thanks Max.  I didn't know that it wouldn't add the translation if it found the word in the phrasebook.

Answer (score 0):

The phrasebook is just a hint/help for the human translator, `lupdate` will never automatically translate anything for you. Any translations in the .ts file still need to be populated and/or marked as completed "manually" (typically in QtLinguist, but one could use any text editor, or a script, or whatever).